# three.js using controls/PointerLockControls.js - make camera move where it's facing in Z axis?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using the example code from the three.js git:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/PointerLockControls.js

How can I change it so, instead of W/S moving only on the original Z axis, my camera moves where I look at? So, if I look up, I would move up.

I tried reading about this from other questions, but can't figure out the exact line of code I need, as I'm new to three.js. The other examples in the GIT didn't help me either, but rather confused me further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried different things, and found the simplest answer to work. I'm not sure if it's efficient, though.

```
if (moveForward) camera.translateZ(-moveSpeed * speedMultiplier);
if (moveBackward) camera.translateZ(moveSpeed * speedMultiplier);

if (moveLeft) camera.translateX(-moveSpeed * speedMultiplier);
if (moveRight) camera.translateX(moveSpeed * speedMultiplier);

if (moveUp) camera.translateY(moveSpeed * speedMultiplier);
if (moveDown) camera.translateY(-moveSpeed * speedMultiplier);
```

I'm using the same event boolean variables, but instead of all the "delta" and stuff code, I just use this simplified version. Simple translations. [speedMultiplier lets me toggle speed with the SHIFT key, with another key event.]